# Uninstalling python library installed from github clone

Tags: python, git, theano

Can you tell me how should I uninstall Theano which I developed by cloning the Theano Git Repository?

I have:

```
$pip freeze | grep Theano
-e git://github.com/Theano/Theano.git@18319b8f426e99fa209c4910af7208c0d51c41a6#egg=Theano
```

`sudo pip uninstall Theano` returns `Can't uninstall 'Theano'. No files were found to uninstall.`

`sudo pip install Theano` gives:

```
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): theano in ./Theano
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): numpy>=1.7.1 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy-1.12.0.dev0+1436ec3-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg (from theano)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): scipy>=0.11 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from theano)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): six>=1.9.0 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from theano)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably not in the directory, where you were installing Theano.

I thinky, you have following options::

```
$ pip uninstall Theano/
```

This works for me (tested with `moto` as installing Theano requires some compiled packages which are
failing on my machine).

Another option is to `cd` to the Theano dir and uninstal from here::

```
$ cd Theano
$ pip uninstall theano
```

If none of this works, last option is to manually remove it from system by deleting the
Theano.egg-link file.

Assuming you are using virtualenv named `testtheano`::

```
$ cd ~/.virtualenvs/testtheano/lib/python2.7/site-packages
$ rm Theano.egg-link
```

If it installed some scripts, delete them too:

```
$ cd ~/.virtualenvs/testtheano/bin
$ rm <all-the-theano-scripts>
```

Answer (score 0):

Find out where it's installed:

```
$ which Theano
```

and remove it.

The dependencies shouldn't cause you any harm and can be left in place. If you want to remove them, you can, but be careful, since they may well be required by other packages.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply remove the Theano directory and egg file from /opt/anaconda/lib/pythonXX/site-packages.